# How to plot a graph which depicts the perfomance of a ML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph

I have done binary classification for a dataset to determine whether there is a leak or no-leak.I have applied 3 ML algorithms separately for comparing performance namely naive-bayes,random forest and decision tree.for the decision tree classifier i have done the following code where s1 to s20 are sensor values how can i plot an error analysis graph.Since i have the predicted output as either 0 or 1

```py
#creating features and labels
n_features = list(zip(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13,s14,s15,s16,s17,s18,s19,s20))
n_samples = status
#Decision tree  regression
clf = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
#spliting of data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(n_features,n_samples, test_size=0.5,random_state=0)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_std = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_std = sc.fit_transform(X_test)
#train model
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
#prediction
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_std)
print('percentage Accuracy:',100*metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe called `model_performance_df`. Add the machine learning algorithms you have used `Naive Bayes, RandomForest and DecisionTree` as the column names in the dataframe. Add those performance metrics for each algorithm in the dataframe.

Use the visualization library `matplotlib` or `seaborn` to plot the graph as you like. Example, give a try `Histogram` or `Distribution plot`.